# apache proxy configuration for socket.io (project not in root)

Tags: node.js, apache, proxy, socket.io

I know there are several questions like this but i can't find one solving my problem for a project which is not in the server root.
I have the following situation: I have an Apache server which runs several projects like:

```
 0.0.0.0/project1
 0.0.0.0/project2
```

I added a node.js project let's call it `nodeproject`. With ProxyPass I am passing  requests made to `0.0.0.0/nodeproject` to `0.0.0.0:8080` where my node server is running. This is all working fine except the websocket configuration for socket.io.

In my `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file i placed this code to do the proxying. `mod_proxy_wstunnel` is enabeld Which i basically copied from [here](https://gist.github.com/kassius/954e0787d6893c5ab8e1).

```
ProxyRequests off
ProxyVia on

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/nodeproject/socket.io            [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket    [NC]
RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://localhost:8080/$1 [P,L]

ProxyPass        /nodeproject/socket.io http://localhost:8080/socket.io
ProxyPassReverse /nodeproject/socket.io http://localhost:8080/socket.io

<Location /nodeproject>
    ProxyPass http://localhost:8080
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080
</Location>
```

The failing request looks like this:

```
ws://0.0.0.0/nodeproject/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=MDuVcHmt3T1sa8ruAAAa
```

and i get a Bad Request 400 response.

I am not an expert in configuring this kind of stuff where did I go wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You shouldn't put the rewrite conditional in the `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, but in the virtual host directive `in /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-project-whatever.conf`.

Here's an example from one of my own little projects.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName sockey.api
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/sockey.api
<Directory /var/www/sockey.api>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorDocument 404 /index.html
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/sockey.api.error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/sockey.api.access.log combined

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/socket.io            [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket    [NC]
RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://localhost:8081/$1 [P,L]

ProxyPass        /socket.io http://localhost:8081/socket.io
ProxyPassReverse /socket.io http://localhost:8081/socket.io

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: So how do you reference ```sockey.api``` as your host?

Comment: How would I go about implementing HTTPS using letsencrypt?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use Apache as a proxy for socket.io using this configuration:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=polling [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /socket.io/socket.io.js
RewriteRule /socket.io/(.*)$ http://localhost:8082/socket.io/$1 [P]
ProxyPass /socket.io/ ws://localhost:8082/socket.io/
ProxyPassReverse /socket.io/ ws://localhost:8082/socket.io/
```

It takes into account that there are two types of requests going over https: the request for the js file `socket.io.js` itself, and the polling requests.